# Spring - How to map JSON form data to Controller paramater

Tags: json, spring, forms, model-view-controller, controller

I'm having a little trouble sending form data as a JSON, and handling it with the controller. What is the "best" way to approach this, using spring annotations?

My hope was that I could send the form data to the controller as an object, and have the controller map it to the model automatically, but im receiving an error

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Form

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Please enter name below to register</h2>
    <br>
    <h1>User Name</h1>
    <form  method="post" action="/SpringRedirecting/process/" enctype="application/json">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="uname" value="" />
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="password" value="" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String processRequest(@RequestBody final User user, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest req){         
    map.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "output";   
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the form is indeed submitted as JSON?

Comment: Hi JBNizet, I have set the enctype as JSON is this enough?

Comment: The spec says: *During the transition period, user agents that do not support this encoding will fall back to using application/x-www-form-urlencoded.*. Why don't you check what goes over the network, using your browser console?

Comment: Also, if you haven't configured a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`  bean inside a `<mvc:message-converters>` block, then Jackson isn't going to be used to automatically deserialize your User from JSON into an object.

Comment: @Jnanathan Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have an object that has same format with your form data. I suppose your `User` have `uname` and `password` fields, Then Your form must provide these two fields. You can do following:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(){
    var data = {};
    data['uname'] = $('[name="uname"]').val();
    data['password'] = $('[name="password"]').val();
    $.ajax({
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/SpringRedirecting/process/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {

    },
    success: function(data) {

    },

   return false; //Prevent normal submitting of the form
});
```

Then you can access `data` in your controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public String processRequest(@RequestBody final User user, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest req){ 
        System.out.printLn(user.getUname());        
        //This will print the value of first input.
     }
```

**Notes**:

1. Your model must have setters and getters.
2. Sending object via json format, only works in ajax request. You can't submit form in normal way if you want to use json.